# how to send a call_action in fritzconnect

Tags: python-3.x, action, call, fritzbox

everybody,

I use Python3 and fritzconnection to connect to my Fritzbox. Getting information works great, but there are also some commands where you have to send information to get the Fritzbox to respond specifically. How do I do that?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
from fritzconnection import FritzConnection
fc = FritzConnection(password='MyRoommateSucks')
print(fc.call_action('WANCommonInterfaceConfig', 'GetAddonInfos'))
print(fc.call_action('WLANConfiguration:1', 'SetEnable', NewEnable = True))
```

So first call worked fine, but second does not. However here is the method **call_action** I am using from the class **FritzConnection** :

```
def call_action(self, service_name, action_name, **kwargs):
    """Executes the given action. Raise a KeyError on unkown actions."""
    action = self.services[service_name].actions[action_name]
    return action.execute(**kwargs)
```

I guess I assume right if I also put here the **execute** method, since the arguments where give to the method.

```
def execute(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Calls the FritzBox action and returns a dictionary with the arguments.
    """
    headers = self.header.copy()
    headers['soapaction'] = '%s#%s' % (self.service_type, self.name)
    data = self.envelope.strip() % self._body_builder(kwargs)
    url = 'http://%s:%s%s' % (self.address, self.port, self.control_url)
    auth = None
    if self.password:
        auth=HTTPDigestAuth(self.user, self.password)
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, auth=auth)
    # lxml needs bytes, therefore response.content (not response.text)
    result = self.parse_response(response.content)
    return result
```

And here is the necessary method from fritzconnection for **parse_response**

```
def parse_response(self, response):
    """
    Evaluates the action-call response from a FritzBox.
    The response is a xml byte-string.
    Returns a dictionary with the received arguments-value pairs.
    The values are converted according to the given data_types.
    TODO: boolean and signed integers data-types from tr64 responses
    """
    result = {}
    root = etree.fromstring(response)
    for argument in self.arguments.values():
        try:
            value = root.find('.//%s' % argument.name).text
        except AttributeError:
            # will happen by searching for in-parameters and by
            # parsing responses with status_code != 200
            continue
        if argument.data_type.startswith('ui'):
            try:
                value = int(value)
            except ValueError:
                # should not happen
                value = None
        result[argument.name] = value
    return result
```

And here is what the Fritzbox want's:

```
Actionname:         SetEnable
                    ('NewEnable', 'in', 'boolean')

Actionname:         GetInfo
                    ('NewAllowedCharsPSK', 'out', 'string')
                    ('NewAllowedCharsSSID', 'out', 'string')
                    ('NewBSSID', 'out', 'string')
                    ('NewBasicAuthenticationMode', 'out', 'string')
                    ('NewBasicEncryptionModes', 'out', 'string')
                    ('NewBeaconType', 'out', 'string')
                    ('NewChannel', 'out', 'ui1')
                    ('NewEnable', 'out', 'boolean')
                    ('NewMACAddressControlEnabled', 'out', 'boolean')
                    ('NewMaxBitRate', 'out', 'string')
                    ('NewMaxCharsPSK', 'out', 'ui1')
                    ('NewMaxCharsSSID', 'out', 'ui1')
                    ('NewMinCharsPSK', 'out', 'ui1')
                    ('NewMinCharsSSID', 'out', 'ui1')
                    ('NewSSID', 'out', 'string')
                    ('NewStandard', 'out', 'string')
                    ('NewStatus', 'out', 'string')
```

Summary: How is the right syntax for my call_action if I want to send Information.

Comment: A link to the [repo](https://github.com/kbr/fritzconnection/blob/master/fritzconnection/core/fritzconnection.py#L248) `call_action` helps for people like me having no clue.

Comment: A start would be my [repo](https://github.com/tik9/fritzbox) where I did `getinfo` and `setenable` like **kbr** but on a starter level and with different scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Informations are sent by keyword-parameters (as you have done).
Instead of using True|False use 1|0 to enable or disable the WLAN. Some FritzBoxes also use 'WLANConfiguration:2' for the 5GHz band and 'WLANConfiguration:3' for the guest network.

```
fc.call_action('WLANConfiguration:1', 'SetEnable', NewEnable=1)
```

Comment: thanks kbr, I think you own the repo. Can I read the the wifi password with `tr064`?